# Extract values from Json

Tags: java, regex, json

I am using `org.json.simple.JSon` and I have a JSON `Array` of JSON objects like this:

```
{"longitude:":-1.0,"latitude:":1.0},
{"longitude:":1.0,"latitude:":1.0},
{"longitude:":1.0,"latitude:":-1.0},
{"longitude:":-1.0,"latitude:":-1.0}
```

I need to extract values for longitudes and latitudes in to a list like this
`[-1.0,1.0]`
`[1.0,1.0]`

Is there a way to do so using Json or using regex?

Comment: Is it valid JSON string? test it at [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Just create `JSONArray` from JSON string and get the `JSONObject` at each index of `JSONArray` and get the desired values.

**Note:** enclose the string `[...]` to make it valid JSON string.

sample code:

```
String json = "[{\"longitude:\":-1.0,\"latitude:\":1.0},{\"longitude:\":1.0,\"latitude:\":1.0}]";
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println("longitude:" + jsonObject.getDouble("longitude:"));
    System.out.println("latitude:" + jsonObject.getDouble("latitude:"));
}
```

Valid JSON string: (Notice the colon `:` used in key as well)

```
[
    {
        "longitude:": -1,
        "latitude:": 1
    },
    {
        "longitude:": 1,
        "latitude:": 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (uses json.simple like you need but note that there are other JSON Java libraries that might even be better):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class PrintJsonArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String s = "[{\"longitude:\":-1.0,\"latitude:\":1.0},{\"longitude:\":1.0,\"latitude:\":1.0},{\"longitude:\":1.0,\"latitude:\":-1.0},{\"longitude:\":-1.0,\"latitude:\":-1.0}]";
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(s);
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
            double longitude = (double) json.get("longitude:");
            double latitude = (double) json.get("latitude:");
            l.add("[" + longitude + "," + latitude + "]");
        }
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

Please note 2 things:

1. In order for the JSON you supplied to be a valid one you need to add '[' and ']' surrounding your JSON.
2. You have an ':' in the longitude/latitude attribute names - not sure that this is what you meant (but of course this is only cosmetic)...

Answer (score 0):

```
  ^.*?(?=longitude:":).*?(-?\d+\.\d+).*?(?=latitude:":).*?(-?\d+\.\d+).*$
```

Try this.This will give you all the values.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sM9gJ5/1